# Use iptables to filter HTTPS (with known key)

Tags: ssl, iptables, https

I need to filter an HTTPS URL using iptables, on servers where I have access to the keys involved in the SSL communications with the client.

I have found lots of resources saying that this can't be done if the user does *not* know the keys, but I do - so I wondered if there is a way of having iptables decrypt the URL using the key and then make filtering decisions on that basis.

I assume not but I live in hope!

Comment: You're trying to implement SSL striping, and doing a man in the middle attack where you act as a proxy between the victim and the server theyre visiting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you are knocking on wrong door. `iptables` is great tool but it is doing a little bit different stuff than what you are looking for. It is like how to operate with nails using plastic spoon - may work but not the best tool for it...

In general I would prefer some reverse proxy to do this job:

- accept the connection / handle ssl handshake
- apply filtering rule
- based on the result deny of allow future communication

It is hard to say what is the best - the best is what you know the best ;-). In case I should sort it by system footprint (no extra research - own experience / feeling) I would think about this order

- **haproxy** (reverse proxy with very good ratio resources / performance)

Quite easy to start with. It can do exactly what you need.

- *nginx* (http server with reverse proxy feature)

Http server with reverse proxy feature. It can also solve your issue but as it is just one of the feature there is much more available than you need...

- *Apache httpd*

I have put Apache httpd to the end as it allow you to do almost anything, but the configuration may be the quite difficult if you want to have it correct and you are just beginning with it. As you know more options / possibilities often mean more changes to make a mistake ;-).

Comment: I feared this was the case! Thanks for the input though, it is useful. I think we will probably end up writing our own reverse proxy for this task.